# Looking for revenue data of bitcoin related websites

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, currencies

I was wondering if we can share pointers or anectodes about revenues of web projects related to bitcoin or general cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score -1):

The blockchain itself is literally a database of every transaction ever, so if you download it and parse through all of the transactional data, I guess that probably qualifies as 'revenue related stats'.

[Blockchain.info has a lot of stats](https://blockchain.info/charts) that you may find interesting.

Comment: Technically that is a valid answer haha but I meant something like *projectx.com made $y in z duration.*

Comment: Look up the stats on recent ICOs/token sales. They are literally a public sale for a stake in a project/tokens/whatever-the-idea-is, so you should be able to find numbers on how much money each of these projects / companies was able to raise. Not really revenue, but probably relevant.

Comment: true but majority of them have no proper business model let alone revenue haha